# Can I use gsconnect on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, file-sharing, kde-connect

So I always wanted to find a app with which I can transfer files from my android phone to pc directly without using any cables. Recently I came upon a post where it said gsconnect have to installed on pc and kde connent on phone but it was about Ubuntu 18.04. It didn't said anything about Ubuntu 16.04. So will gsconnect support on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Are you using using GNOME or Unity (default in 16.04)? If it's the later, then simply using KDE Connect with the KDE Connect Indicator would be enough for your purpose.

Comment: I have unity so I guess will have to do with KDE

Answer (score 0):

Developer [says](https://github.com/andyholmes/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/issues/58) that GSConnect relies on Gnome Shell 3.24+. Latest Gnome Shell version in the Xenial official repositories is 3.18, and in GNOME3 Staging PPA it's 3.20, so that doesn't satisfy GSConnect requirements.

As an alternative, you could use SSHDroid to set up SSH server on your Android phone and then transfer the files via SCP/SFTP (natively supported by most file managers (like Nautilus or Dolphin), just enter the displayed sftp address as location).